# Unable to read csv file on Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I imported these libraries and trying to read a CSV file on my desktop

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_M.csv')
```

But I get an error saying

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_onlytweets_M'
```

Comment: The error and your code don't match up.  Please include the full traceback.

Comment: @Yoshith is your problem solved by [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68631283/12446721) if that solved your issue then mark that as accepted answer, if you like my effort you may upvote it. If any further queries ask in comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have to specify a complete path(Absolute path) like this :

```
C:/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_M.csv
```

If you do

```
/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_M.csv
```

then It will search for `Users` folder in working directory, which is not there so, you're getting that error.

Comment: Additionally, you have copied error from one code and your given code is different.

Comment: Please check your path. I repeated your error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_M.csv'

Comment: @lazy I don't understand your comment! Can  you please explain clearly?

Comment: Rerun your code, You can see the same mistakes as me.The absolute path of the desktop is: click Disk C, click the user folder, click the window user folder, and then you can see the data on the desktop. This path is complete. As answered.

Comment: @lazy whom are you really telling that! Are you the same person who asked question? what do you mean by _"Rerun your code, You can see the same mistakes as me"_?

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. I thought the subject didn't understand. I'm sorry. Your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Xitiz I am getting the error " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/verymimi_M.csv' " after using the absolute path as well

Comment: All of a sudden, But now its working, omfg i donno how but thanks for your help @Xitiz

Comment: You can mark this as an accepted answer as well @YoshithKotla :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on online jupyter notebook and i did clear cache on my browser and my csv file opened magically

Comment: What do you mean specifically by 'online Jupyter Notebook'? Was it a pyodide kernel? JupyterLite? Running a full Pyton kernel on a remote machine? The original post you are posting in specifically referenced the CSV being on the Desktop and I don't think Pyodide or JupyterLite were around in 2021.